# C / C++ Server returns nothing , how client can know socket or ethernet connection down/broken?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, networking, tcp

The server is not sending any feedback or messages but keepalive support is available.

How can the client understand that the connection is broken or socket closed?

I want to instantly detect client disconnection from client side. I need to find a way to discover asap that the client has disconnected from the socket.

Since there is keepalive on the server side, if there is a disconnection on the client side, it closes the socket. However, the client side still continues to write to the buffer. I need to check the instant connection and close the client socket.

server code ;

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>   
#include <iostream>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int server_fd, new_socket, valread;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int opt = 1;
    int addrlen = sizeof(address);
    char buffer[1024] = {0};
    int flags = 1;

    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0)
    {
        perror("socket failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(opt)))
    {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    flags = 10;
    if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_TCP, TCP_KEEPIDLE, (void *)&flags, sizeof(flags))) { perror("ERROR: setsocketopt(), SO_KEEPIDLE"); exit(0); };

    flags = 2;
    if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_TCP, TCP_KEEPCNT, (void *)&flags, sizeof(flags))) { perror("ERROR: setsocketopt(), SO_KEEPCNT"); exit(0); };

    flags = 2;
    if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_TCP, TCP_KEEPINTVL, (void *)&flags, sizeof(flags))) { perror("ERROR: setsocketopt(), SO_KEEPINTVL"); exit(0); };

    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.4.28");
    address.sin_port = htons( 6000 );

    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address))<0)
    {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (listen(server_fd, 3) < 0)
    {
        perror("listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,(socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0)
    {
        perror("accept");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    flags =1;
    if (setsockopt(new_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (void *)&flags, sizeof(flags))) { perror("ERROR: setsocketopt(), SO_KEEPALIVE"); exit(0); };

    while(valread = read(new_socket , buffer, 1024) > 0 && new_socket > 0)
    {
        std::cout << "valread : " << valread << std::endl;
        std::cout << "new_socket : " << new_socket << std::endl;
        printf("%s\n",buffer );
        buffer[1024] = {0};
    }

    close(server_fd);
    close(new_socket);

    return 0;
}
```

client code ;

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>  
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include<iostream>

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int socket_desc;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char *message;

    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.4.28");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( 6000 );

    if (connect(socket_desc , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
    {
        puts("connect error");
        return 1;
    }

    puts("Connected\n");
    message = "test";

    for(int i = 1; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        sleep(1);
        //Send some data
        if( send(socket_desc , message , strlen(message) , 0) < 0)
        {
            puts("Send failed");
        }
        std::cout << ("%d",i) << ". test data send" << std::endl;
    }

    close(socket_desc);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what happens the client does `send( ...` and the connection is broken ? And what do you want to happen ?

Comment: I want the send() function to somehow return false after the internet connection is broken on the client side.

Comment: Not the way sockets work, I'm afraid. You write into the socket and `send` returns so that the program can get on with its job whether the data was sent or not. The network stack will make sure the data gets sent in the background. If it doesn't get sent... You'll only find that out if you keep writing to the socket and fill the socket's buffer or you `close` and find that it's taking a really, really long time to return. TCP/IP's job is to send data or die trying, and you typically don't want to sit around and wait through the retries.

Comment: @tryingBetter Unless the *server* side explicitly closes/resets the connection, `send()` on the *client* side can't detect a lost connection in a timely manner. There is a timeout period that must elapse before the OS on the client side will invalidate a dead connection. Until that happens, `send()` doesn't know anything is wrong, it will happily keep buffering data until the buffer fills up, and then the socket will block further sends until the OS invalidates the connection...

Comment: @tryingBetter ... All you can really do on the *client* side is enable keep-alives with your own timeout period, and/or use `setsockopt()` to enable `SO_SENDTIMEO` on `send()`

Comment: See:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/40155355/131930